# Unable to decrypt using jasypt : Illegal Block Size Exception

Tags: java, jasypt, java-security

I am using **Jasypt** to encrypt and decrypt sensitive data in the properties files.
I started noticing the `IllegalBlockSizeException`. I updated jasypt code to figure out what is the actual error (By default jasypt masks the `Error` and throws `org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException`)

The encrypt and decrypt works perfectly fine on my development machine. When i copy the jars built either locally or using Jenkins i am seeing this error.

The local JDK version i am using is:

```
λ java -version
java version "1.8.0_202"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.202-b08, mixed mode)
```

And here are the jdk versions we have on the server (i tried with multiple versions and getting the same error)

```
java version "1.8.0_191"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b26, mixed mode)
```

and

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_201"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode)
```

Exception in Logs:

> Salt Size Bytes=[8]
>       Encrypted Message Length=[21]
>       javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher
>               at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:936)
>               at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:847)
>               at com.sun.crypto.provider.PKCS12PBECipherCore.implDoFinal(PKCS12PBECipherCore.java:399)
>               at com.sun.crypto.provider.PKCS12PBECipherCore$PBEWithSHA1AndDESede.engineDoFinal(PKCS12PBECipherCore.java:431)
>               at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2164)
>               at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.decrypt(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:1041)
>               at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor.decrypt(StandardPBEStringEncryptor.java:725)

I wrote a test utility and compiled it on the Server and ran the tests to encrypt and decrypt and they are working fine. which means the policies in the JRE are not the Issue.

Thanks
sateesh

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve the issue.it's a stupid mistake.

The value that is set to the decrypted property in a Spring bean is set as concateation of two properties from prop file!!

Adding the debug statements to actually log what values that are being decrypted helped in resolving the issue.